# What is the address of a restricted channel in Masked Authenticated Messaging (MAM)?

Tags: tangle, address, masked-authenticated-messaging, hashing

I have read many research papers, articles and the iota documentation. However, I am still confused whether the address for restricted mode is

hash(merkle root) or hash(side_key + merkle root)

Please someone let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the docs and actual implementation seem to contradict each other.

If you follow what is now indicated to be the official implementation of MAM in javascript, then [this line](https://github.com/iotaledger/mam.js/blob/master/src/mam/channel.ts#L139) tells us that both private and restricted mode use the hash of the merkle root as address.

In the implementation the side key is only used as a revocable encryption key.